# Theory behind the destructive interference in PhET's wave on a string simulation

Tags: waves, interference

After about 11 seconds, regardless of what frequency the system is driven at, the waves will succinctly cancel.

[image]

https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulations/wave-on-a-string

How?

I was playing with it earlier and thought the time at which it occurred would change with changing frequency... it does not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing periodicity in this simulation of waves on a string. If $\psi(x,t)$ is the vertical displacement of the string at position $x$ and time $t$, then
$$
\psi(x,\tau)=\psi(x,0).
$$
For the system in your screenshot above, I measured $\tau$ to be exactly $12$ seconds. General descriptions of waves on a string with moving boundary conditions have the potential to be quite complex. To the best of my knowledge, this is because the spatial and temporal parts of $\psi(x,t)$ are not always guaranteed to be separable, as they are with standing waves. By this, I mean that in general
$$
\psi(x,t) \neq X(x)T(t).
$$
Due to this complication, I cannot think of a rigorous way to predict if such a $\tau$ exists, and if it exists, how to express $\tau$ in terms of the system parameters.

We can guarantee, however, that $\tau=\frac{n}{2f}$, where $f$ is the forcing frequency and $n$ is some integer. This is because the left boundary condition $\psi(0,t)=F\sin(2\pi f t)$ must always be satisfied. For $\tau=12$ seconds, $n=18$. This condition implies that forcing frequency **does** play a role in determining $\tau$.

It is also reasonable to expect that $\tau=mL/c$, i.e., that the period of the field coincides with the arrival of the original front at one of the boundaries. Here, $L$ is the length of the string, $c$ is the wave speed, and $m$ is a positive integer. Together with the condition based on $f$, we can guess that $\tau$ will be the first common multiple of $1/f$ and $L/c$. $L/c = 1.2$ seconds for the provided system. After some testing, this seems to be the case. For example, if $f=1.80$ Hz, I find that $\tau=1$ minute. For $f=2.4$ Hz, $\tau=30$ seconds.